# FQL - select friends with adequate photo permissions

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am running an app that vacuums in all of your friend's photos upon user request.  Things go Ok, except that maybe 35% of FB users have set their photos to not be accessible to apps.  (or at least I assume that is what happening - users who I know to have photos and albums show no photos and empty albums)

My question then is 1.5 part:  Is this what is actually happening, and what sort of FQL query should I use to get a filtered friend list that only shows friends who's photos you can access?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure on this at all, but I think a decent starting off point would be

```
SELECT friends_photos FROM permissions WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

Which is a multiquery which grabs friends, then queries them to see if they allow access.